# On Ubuntu 18.04, snap apps don't appear in the Dash

Tags: gnome, zsh, ubuntu-18.04, dash

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and a few snap apps (Slack, Spotify). Snap apps don't show up in the regular "app list" when I search for an app, and I don't understand why.

I'm running zsh, so I found an article about zsh not adding the snap "volume" to my path. I've fixed that by adding:

```
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh'
```

To my .zshrc file.

This means that I can run `which spotify` and it shows up, pointing to the snap volume (so I can start Spotify from the terminal).

I've also ensured that there is a `.desktop` file bundled in the Spotify snap app.

Still, I'd like apps to show up when I search for them.

EDIT: Yesterday my apps magically started appearing. I guess some Ubuntu update took care of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have only been able to make it work by changing my default shell to /bin/bash (with `chsh` and rebooting) and using /bin/zsh only at the gnome terminal level. I use zsh too.